# Implement urlMatcherFactoryProvider-like behavior using Angular 2 Router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, angular2-routing

We have a system using AngularJS and ui.router that supports the following URL schema:

`www.domain.com/user/event`

`www.domain.com/user/group/subgroup/event`

`www.domain.com/user/group/subgroup/event/_/detail/itemID`

This is setup as follows:
```
    $urlMatcherFactoryProvider.type('nonURIEncoded', {
      encode: valToString,
      decode: valFromString,
      is: regexpMatches,
      pattern: /(?:(?!/_).)*/
    });

```
$stateProvider
  .state('main.view', {
    url: '/_/:view/:id'
  })
  ...
  .state('main', {
    url: '{path: nonURIEncoded}',
    ...
  });
```

```

Basically, the regex makes sure to catch everything up until and `/_/` and give that to us as `path`, and this way we can also match sub routes/states that can be optional for different views.

The question is how to best do that using the Angular 2 router and whether it is even possible to match things that contain `/`.

We currently configure the router to  `{ path: ':userId/:eventId', }` but that of course wouldn't work once there would be an additional levels of hierarchy. We would kind of need some sort of catch-all or mechanism as we used in the previous one.

Thanks a lot for any insights!